# Why arguments to dictionary[] are interpreted as a single key?

Tags: python

If I declare a dictionary like:

```
a = {(1, 2, 3): 10, (4, 5, 6):20}
```

the I can reference the elements as using the keys as:

```
a[(1, 2, 3)]
```

why this:

```
a[1, 2, 3]
```

results in the same operation? If is were a function it should raise an error since I am passing three parameters instead of one.

Comment: You _aren't passing args to the dict, you are indexing it via a key, which is a rather different process to passing args to a function that you're calling.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[1, 2, 3]
```

It takes as a tuple.

```
>>>a = 1,2,3
>>>type(a)
tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

`1, 2, 3` is a tuple, just like `(1, 2, 3)`. Tuples are defined by the commas. The parentheses are for grouping in cases that might otherwise be ambiguous.

Comment: why this is different from functions? `def f(a): pass; f(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @RuggeroTurra, "_The parentheses are for grouping in cases that might otherwise be ambiguous_".

Comment: I don't think this answers. In case of function call the `,` seems to separate arguments, while when using `[ ]` it seems to define a tuple. So: is `[ ]` a function just with a special syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You're still passing in a tuple, just using other syntax.

`(a, b, c, d)` is the same as `a, b, c, d`, they both construct a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Because declaring x,y,z is a implicit way of declaring a tuple. Try this:

```
 >>> n = 1,2
 >>> n
 (1, 2)
```

Comment: More that implicit, it's _the_ way of declaring a tuple. The parenthesizes just do nothing here. Thus `(1, 2)` is the same as `1, 2` the same way `(1)` is the same as `1`.